# Library for parsing GoLang stack traces?

Tags: go

I'm trying to detect goroutine leaks in my Go tests. However, the existing libraries I've seen all detect global leaks, not leaks of goroutines which are descendents of the test function. I want this functionality for two reasons:

1. It allows me to detect leaks while still running tests in parallel (e.g. using `t.Parallel()`)
2. It will ignore leaks which are just the fault of `init` functions. This happens a lot in our codebase because we have, for example, a logging library imported which creates a long-running goroutine in its `init` function.

This is now possible with the addition of `GODEBUG=tracebackancestors=n` ([proposal](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/22289), [docs](https://www.google.com/search?q=tracebackancestors+golang&rlz=1C5GCEM_en&oq=tracebac&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j0i512j69i64j0i512j69i60j69i61l2.3433j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)).

In lieue of an existing leak detection library which does what I want, I'd like to build my own, but I don't want to write my own logic for parsing the output of `runtime.Stack` because it's just an unstructured string. I'd like a library which can give me the actual parsed, structured, stack/goroutine information. Is there an existing library which does this? Alternatively, is there a goroutine leak detection library which does what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a pull request for this for [gostackparse](https://github.com/DataDog/gostackparse) at https://github.com/DataDog/gostackparse/pull/3. If this gets accepted, let's just update this answer to say that it's supported by the package.